# Configure WHM Main IP to redirect to an specific account

Tags: php, apache, cpanel, httpd.conf, whm

I'm working on a project that has a single domain on a WHM Server. So we access through an IP to the Wordpress Installation that is on the only account (Cpanel): `server/~account1/`.

To be more clear, when we access to `http://xxx.xxx.xxx/` we were actually accesing to `http://xxx.xxx.xxx/~account1/`.

After a server migration, however, this stopped working, so we are trying to make it work again. I'm trying to figure out what is wrong here.

Now when we browse to `http://xxx.xxx.xxx/` we get the default webpage `http://xxx.xxx.xxx/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi`, but we can access the real directory by typing the `/~account1/`.

Can you help me to figure where to start looking or what could be the problem? Could i fix it by editing the `httpd.conf`?

I'm a programmer but not an expert of server configuration so I'm kinda lost.

Comment: You might have more luck getting answers by flagging this post for migration to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 0):

httpd.conf would be the place to start.

You are looking to check the Virtual Hosts setings, often in the above file or `conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

If all else fails, try running the httpd.conf rebuild script as root:

```
/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf
```